# Sequential actions in Flux

Tags: javascript, flux

Every once in a while, I run into a situation where I need to fire multiple actions in succession. With Facebook's implementation of Flux, doing this results in an error being thrown: "Cannot dispatch in the middle of a dispatch." Obviously there is some reason for this error, so I'm wondering how to structure my application differently.

Here's an example scenario where this might occur:

> 1. A user tries to log-in, but provides the wrong credentials
> 2. An action is fired called `failedToAuth`
> 3. A service called `ErrorHandler` is listening for `failedToAuth` action
> 4. Depending on the error, `ErrorHandler` may redirect the user to another page or create an error notification
>
> In the case of the 4th situation, another action may be fired. For
>   example, it might be a `redirectToPage` action or a `createError`
>   action. Unfortunately, these cannot be fired without the
>   aforementioned error thrown.

Another example:

> 1. When the application first loads, it needs to retrieve some state data.
> 2. It performs a request to the server and upon retrieving the result, it fires 3-4 actions that each have some parameters for the retrieved
>      data.
> 3. Several stores may be listening to these actions which have their own domain logic to handle the data retrieved.
>
> Again, the dispatch error is thrown. I could create a big meta action
>   called `serverResponse` that has all the data so its in one action
>   rather than many. However, this seems like a case of [tight coupling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_%28computer_programming%29),
>   which would be another vice.

So what is the proper way to solve situations that call for sequential actions being fired?

**Note: I know I can use setTimeout, but doing so would just be a hack to get around an error that exists for a reason.**

Answer (score 2):

I think the issue here is that you're placing the responsibility for updating the RouteStore's state in the ErrorHandlerStore, which is not the right place. If a store's state is affected by an action, it should know about that action rather than moving that knowledge somewhere else. So, instead, if you have a route store, have that listen to the failedToAuth action and update the route accordingly for applicable cases. If you want to put the logic to decide the route change in the ErrorHandlerStore, you'll have to have the RouteStore wait for that store (using waitFor) and read the info it needs out of ErrorStore, but that isn't necessarily the best way; probably an ErrorStore should be responsible for error message state, but it isn't really responsible for routing. You can have a separate ErrorHandler module to centralize error handling logic, and have both stores (e.g. Route and ErrorMessage) call into that to decide how to update their state - there are lots of options depending on your needs.

In the second case, if it makes sense to fire multiple actions, because it's easier to process it in sections and nothing needs to see it all, that's not necessarily a problem - you can dispatch actions sequentially one by one without any problems, since each will be processed synchronously so each dispatch will finish before the next starts. If you're using React, the only thing is you need to batch them up, to avoid multiple React renders (this is even the case if you are only firing a single action, since a single action might ultimately trigger multiple component setState calls). You'll need some kind of helper in your flux to allow calling multiple actions in batch, which will also call React.addons.batchedUpdates to ensure all setState calls are batched (in fact, you should always use batchedUpdates when handling ajax responses, since otherwise you can end up rendering multiple times).